# What does "Loss Forgiven" mean on the match history?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was going through my match history in League of Legends after losing a few in a row to see how long it's been since I've won a game, and I saw this:

[image]

The game was a few days ago and I unfortunately do not have a very good memory.  What on earth does "Loss Forgiven" mean?  Usually that line either says "Victory" or "Defeat".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If there are server issues during your game that Riot would consider serious enough to affect your gameplay, then any loss will be forgiven due to circumstances outside of your control ([source](http://support.leagueoflegends.com/entries/20027152-loss-forgiven)). This means that your elo and win/loss stats are unaffected by that loss. However, if you win your elo will only increase by half of what it normally would. IP and XP are gained as usual.

I don't believe they forgive losses for teammates leaving the game though (JesterCapp discusses that [here](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=268322&page=3)).